# Линковщик и линковщик динамических библиотек это разные программы?

Tags: c++, linux, elf

1. Линковщик и линковщик динамических библиотек это разные ведь программы?
2. Что именно требуется в системе для запуска исполняемого файла, зависящего от .so? Загрузчик? Или загрузчик и линковщик какой-то особый?
3. Как можно вызывать загрузчик ELF'ов самостоятельно? В интернете пишут, что можно как-то через системный вызов. Т.е. это модуль ядра?

Comment: линковщик - это программа, которая с объектых файлов собирает бинарник. А этот бинарник может быть и elf, и динамической библиоткеой. Линковщик не запускает программу. 

А вот зачем Вам нужно вызывать "системный загрузчик" - это уже интересно. Или Вы просто хотите запустить приложение?

Comment: @KoVadim, словосочетания «системный загрузчик» в вопросе нет. в вопросе есть путаница — словом «линковщик» автор именует и linker и loader. @ Mike *программа ядра* — это тавтология. «масло масляное».

Comment: Первые 2 вопроса я задал про linker. 3й про loader. Имелось ввиду модуль ядра

Comment: Так я не спорю, что у меня иллюзии на этот счет, поэтому и спрашиваю

Comment: второй и третий вопросы у вас — про [загрузчик (loader)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC). который вы путаете с [линковщиком (linker)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA). // а первый вопрос должен звучать как «линковщик и загрузчик (программ и библиотек) — это разные программы?». ответ на него — да.

Comment: вот неплохая статья на английском про разницу между linker и loader: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6463

Comment: 2й вопрос я немного не корректно задал. Имелось ввиду какой именно линковщик/загручик вызывается для исполняемого файла, требующего .so для своей работы.

Comment: @MikeAJ, см. `man ld.so`

Comment: @alexander barakin , стать прочитал. Не сказать, чтобы стало на 100% ясно, кроме того про загрузчик там `почти` ничего нет.  В man ld.so написано, что это loader/linker. В итоге что это(вроде как linker?)? В итоге- правильно ли я понял, что по системному вызову зовется модуль ядра(loader), который зовет ld.so(linker) для релокации библиотеки?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45883/discussion-between-mike-aj-and-alexander-barakin).

Answer (score 1):

Линкер в контексте компиляции это такая штука, которая берет пачку объектных файлов, смотрит каких функций там не хватает(например, printf), потом смотрит системные папки и ищет там недостающие функции(printf лежит в /lib/libc.so). Если все недостающие функции найдены успешно, то запоминает в каких библиотеках они лежат(/lib/libc.so), после чего сшивает все объектные файлы и добавляет информацию о библиотеках. В итоге у тебя файл это код из объектников + инфа о том какие либы нужны и какие функции в этих либах нужно искать.

И тут возникает вторая штука, которая называется загрузчиком или динамическим линкером или динамическим загрузчиком. Это такая программа, которая читает твой бинарник, смотрит какие нужны библиотеки и функции, проверяет есть ли они в системе. Если все есть то загружает в память твой бинарник, загружает нужные либы(например грузит libc по адресу 0x12345678), потом говорит твоей программе, где лежат либы(libc - 0x12345678) и вызывает main.

1. Так вот линковщик для компиляции и обычных исполняемых файлов и для so-шников один и тот же, динамический загрузчик тоже одинаковый.
2. Для того, чтобы запустить исполняемый файл в системе требуется загрузить этот файл, загрузить все либы, от которых зависит файл, потом все либы, от которых зависят эти либы и т. д. После чего сказать им всем, где друг друга искать и вызвать main у программы
3. Я не совсем понимаю, что значит вызвать загрузчик ELF-ов, есть 2 вещи - dlopen, dlsym, dlclose они позволяют динамически грузить либы, и /lib/ld-linux.so это как раз и есть загрузчик, можешь вызвать для примера

```
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 --help
```